# snprintf formatting specifier

Tags: c, string, printf

In my code I use snprintf as below and could able to see the following behaviour

```
char text[30] = {0};

snprintf(text, sizeof(text), "%s", "hello");
printf("Interm... %s\n", text);
snprintf(text, "%20s", text);
printf("At the end ... %s\n", text);
```

### Output

```
Interm... hello
At the end ...
```

As you can see if source and destinaton of snprintf are same, it clears the buffer. I want the output to be in the 20s format specifier. I can't do this in first step itself as I need to append multiple string and do the format specifier at the last step.

Is copying to the temporary buffer and from there to the original buffer the only possible solution? Can you please throw some light on this.

Comment: How is `text` declared?

Comment: The second `snprintf` is bad, but I'm more curious about how the first one turned "kiruba" into "hello"

Comment: The second snprintf() is worse than that...it's missing the buffer size argument.

Comment: @Wumpus : Sorry the type error of putting "kiruba".. now I corrected in question section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `snprintf` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf)

> C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call
>   to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause
>   copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the
>   target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to
>   the same buffer).

This means that the line

```
snprintf(text, "%20s", text)
```

isn't valid.  Your suggestion of using an additional, temporary, buffer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To get your goal accomplished: str1 followed by str2, all of that padded on the left with spaces, or truncated on the right, to a length of (wid) characters, stored in outbuf (which must be at least wid+1 chars wide) you can use just one sprintf...

```
size_t len1=strlen(str1), len2=strlen(str2);
if (len2 > wid-len1) { len2 = wid-len1; }
snprinf(outbuf, wid+1, "%*s%.%s", wid-len2, str1, len2, str2);
```

Note that (wid-len2) is the padded size of str1 on output, and len2 is the truncated size of str2 on output. The wid+1 buffer size in snprintf() is the guard against the pathological case where len1>wid.